# MapStateToProps not being called

Tags: redux, react-redux

I understand questions like this one has been asked numerous times before; but I have exhausted all the resources and options and cannot figure out why this is not working. When I create the action **"AUTHENTICATION_LOGOUT"**  I can trace it up to the action reducer and can see that from the action reducer the new state is returned, however it does not get picked up in the component by `connect` and consequently`mapStateToProps` wont run. I return a new object for state so the check should flag it as a state change not a state mutation, right?
could it be a bug or version mismatch? Thanks.

in auth_actions:

```
export const appLogout = () => async dispatch => {
    await AsyncStorage.removeItem(USER);
    dispatch({ type: "AUTHENTICATION_LOGOUT" });
};
```

in auth_reducer.js

```
export default function (state = {}, action) {
        switch (action.type) {
            case "AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS":
                return { user: action.payload };
            case "AUTHENTICATION_LOGOUT":
                return {user: null };
            default:
                return state;
        }
    }
```

in index.js in the reducers folder:

```
export default combineReducers({
    search, auth
});
```

in AuthComponent.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
class AuthScreen extends Component {
 ...
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    let { auth } = state;
    return { user: auth.user };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(AuthScreen);
```

and the store:

```
const store = createStore(
    reducers,
    {},
    compose(
        applyMiddleware(thunk)
    )
);

export default store;
```

in App.js

```
import store from './store';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <MainNavigation />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "expo": "^27.0.0",
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-27.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
  }
```

**Update**
After a lot of digging I figured what the problem was. The issue here, that of course I failed to see, was the fact that *this component was unmounted and therefore did not received any state update at all*. I checked it with the **componentWillUnmount** life cycle hook. It did not have anything to do with state mutation. I got horribly thrown off by all the talks and posts about state mutation. Thanks everyone for their invaluable help and time.

Comment: Can you be more specific about how assigning a JSON object "breaks things?" Add to your mapStateToProps `console.log(JSON.stringify(state));`

Comment: The first time I log in, I hit mapStateToProps alright. The second time when I set the user to null, mapStateToProps does not get hit at all.

Answer (score 0):

Never use react native so maybe i miss a thing but i believe redux expect the action in dispatch argument to be a function returning the actual action object. Also the function should be import from another file.

check AUTHENTICATION_LOGOUT value is a string

using es6 your mapStateToProps will be better this way:

```
({auth: {user}) => ({user})
```

Comment: dispatch types are all strings.

Comment: Does not necessarily have to be a function that return an object. we can directly plug in a js object with a type and an optional payload. To change something in the state, you need to dispatch an action. An action is a plain JavaScript object. https://redux.js.org/introduction/core-concepts

Comment: why is your initial state an empty object and next states {user} ? Is it possible your removeAppUser function has undesirable side effects ?

Comment: I changed removedAppUser to the actual call to AsyncStorage. Also, It did  not make a difference when I changed the initial state to  state={user: null}.

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to use the [`react-redux` `Provider`](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#provider-store).

Another tip, you can improve your `mapStateToProps` function like this:

```
const mapStateToProps = ({auth}) => auth;
```

or if you are using ramda:

```
const mapStateToProps = prop('auth');
```

You don't need to create a new object in your `mapStateToProps` function because the reducer is already doing that. Notice that `auth` is an object that has a single property: `user`, so you can just grab `auth` from the state and that's it (a little bit less work for the garbage collector :-)).

Comment: No, the provider is there too. I just updated the question with the provider as well. Thanks.

Comment: @BlackLog I assume that in your update you forgot to add the `import` of your `store`... Because the code that you shared is not importing the store before passing it down to the `Provider`

Comment: @BlackLog is this code in a public repo where I can go and have a look at?

Comment: No, its corporate code, hence not in a public repo. sorry. could it be a bug or a version mismatch?